In rust why does combining a u128 struct with a u32 result in a 32 byte struct?
If I do this struct
#[repr(C)]
struct Thing {
   f1: u128
   f2: u32
}

Then I get a size of 32 and an alignment of 16.
Why isn't it just 20 bytes and how can I fix it so it is?
The context is I'm trying to build a struct to represent MMIO data so I need things to be in the right position.
I just tried repr(packed) instead. That seems to work but the docs seems to discourage its use.

Do you not know what "alignment" means? Or are you unaware that the size needs to be an integer multiple of the alignment?

MMIO is one of the cases where #[repr(packed)] does make sense. Just be aware of the limitations -- in particular, that you may be unable to take references to fields of the struct.

Better use read_volatile and write_volatile on individual registers.

The answer was not repr(packed), that did get the size looking right but it just leads to immediate alignment issues.
Solution was to use repr(C), but just go back through my piles of structs and figure out where things were getting misplaced.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
